# sshd_config using a match statement inside an included file

Tags: openssh, sshd

I have the following sshd configuration files:

/etc/ssh/sshd_config:

```
Include /etc/ssh/sshd_config.local

Protocol 2

PermitRootLogin no
StrictModes no
PasswordAuthentication no
PrintMotd no
Banner /etc/ssh-banner
Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server
```

/etc/ssh/sshd_config.local

```
Match Address 10.0.1.17
  Banner none
```

If I test this configuration, it doesn't clear the banner:

```
 % sudo sshd -T -C addr=10.0.1.17 | grep -i baner
banner /etc/ssh-banner
```

But if I move the Match statement to the main file, it works fine:

```
Protocol 2

PermitRootLogin no
StrictModes no
PasswordAuthentication no
PrintMotd no
Banner /etc/ssh-banner
Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server

Match Address 10.0.1.17
  Banner none
```

```
sudo sshd -T -C addr=10.0.1.17 | grep -i banner  
banner none

 % sudo sshd -T | grep -i banner 
banner /etc/ssh-banner
```

I've tried moving the include statement to the beginning of the file and tried using the sshd_config.d/ directory without any luck.

Comment: I've also tried adding a Match All statement below to ensure it doesn't try to match the rest of the file.

When I remove the match part and just include the file with:

banner none

And the include statement at the top of /etc/ssh/sshd_config it also works as expected. The problem seems to be specifically using the Match statement inside an included file.

Comment: Did you try moving the `include` line to the end of the config? I can only guess, but it looks like the `banner` setting from your `.local` conf gets overwritten by the main conf.

Comment: Yes, I have the same suspicion, I just don't understand why. The same thing happens whether the Include statement is in the top or bottom of the file.

Answer (score 10):

Turns out this a known bug in OpenSSH portable:

https://bugzilla.mindrot.org/show_bug.cgi?id=3122

Comment: Allegedly now fixed in 8.4

Comment: and for the record, 8.2p1 still not fixed for this bug